# Where is officially explained "withVariable" View function?

Tags: laravel

I'm not sure this question should be asked here, but I don't know where else, so I hope it is not banned. And if it is, please address me to a place where it should be asked.

I know in Laravel you can pass a variable called "Bar" to a `view` like this:

```
view()->withBar('Foo');
```

but I don't know how do I know, and the most important, where is it 'officially' explained.

I can find it in the __call function in the code (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/View/View.php) but not in the official API.

So, where is it officially explained?

Comment: I've seen it on laracasts.com

Comment: @moraya.re Yes, but you can't find it in the API.

Comment: It is not documented, for what I can find.

Comment: @JiFus Then how can you learn all of the possibilities of the framework? Analyzing the code or by word-of-mouth ?

Comment: @Amarnasan Well I get what you are getting at, but this piece of information is not necessary to make good use of the framework since it's a synonym. It's pretty common to have some functionality which is undocumented in frameworks.

Comment: @JiFus The problem is I've seen people commiting errors because of the existence of methods like withError or withCookies. So, yes: knowing it won't help you make better code, but ignoring it can induce you to make worse code. Anyway, thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use to be documented but it has hasn't been included in the docs since `5.0` https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#passing-data-to-views.

As with most things with Laravel there are usually a few different ways to do the exact same thing so (for whatever reason) somethings do eventually get omitted from the docs but the functionality doesn't get removed. I would imagine this is because it might be considered a bad practice or not the best approach or even that Taylor may eventually want to remove it...who knows. Either way, there is usually an alternative given to achieve the same outcome.

Hope this helps!